# Execute function before anchor tag and load it after

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i execute a function before I click on anchor tag `<a href="/foo" id="foo">Foo</a>` and after click on it ?

I try this :

```
$(document).on('click', '#foo', function(e) {
      // stuff to do
      return false;
}
```

The function is executed but the link /foo is not loading like the default behavior.

Comment: How can you know when user is going to click on anchor?

Comment: @Tushar i didn't understand you !! there a handler for that `$(document).on('click', '#foo', function(e) {...}`

Comment: `return false;` is the reason the link does not load after the event handler. Returning false stops its default action.

Comment: yes I know @AtheistP3ace but how can I do both load the link after executing the function ?

Comment: By not returning `false`? That may sound crazy but I would suggest returning `true`. More seriously if what you're asking for is to execute code after the page has changed, you'll have to handle that on the other page.

Comment: Unless you are calling some asynchronous function just don't return false. Or get the href of the link and load it yourself by setting location.href.

Comment: Well then AtheistP3ace perfectly answers your question. On click the handler you defined will be executed and if it doesn't return false then the event will bubble, triggering the default behaviour of following the link.

Comment: @Aaron  so when i return false the link will not loaded and if i return true it will be triggered , that's right ?

Comment: Returning `false` prevents the event from bubbling, that is being transferred to other handlers, so it will prevent the page change. I'm not too sure returning something else is necessary when you want other handlers to handle the event, you might try just removing the `return false;` as suggested by AtheistP3ace.

Comment: Guys, can we please vote this question up. This is really a normal good question. A basic one, indeed. But nothing wrong in this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I don't understand why people shout at you, being clearer, your question can be answered this way:

```
$(document).on('click', '#foo', function(e) {
  // stuff to do
  alert("Hello");
  // finally follow the link
  location.href = $(this).attr("href");
  // Or may be giving `return true;` could work?
  return false;
}
```

Comment: @Youssef Enjoy buddy! `:)`

Comment: But if we delete last two lines ( `location.href = ...` and `return false`) the result will be same, isn't it ?

Comment: @Youssef I guess so.. You experiment and tell. I will update the answer. `:)`

Comment: @Youssef Out of votes for today. I have asked the others to kindly vote this question up. I will do it tomorrow. `:)` All the best man.